# Can I colour the same text in two different colours?

Tags: node-editor, text-object, color

I want the text to have this sort of colouring
[image]

And this is the text.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. Create two materials, then select the letters in edit mode (shift+keyboard arrows) and assign them to the corresponding material in the material panel

Answer (score 20):

Create two materials, set their colors.

Then enter edit mode in your text.

Select the wanted letters <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>keyboard arrows</kbd>, and assign them to the wanted material.

[image]

General indications to do that using Python:

```
import bpy

# Get the text
o = bpy.data.objects['Text']

# Get all the characters descriptions
characters = [c for c in o.data.body_format.items()]

# Look at it:
for character in characters: 
    # The index of the char
    print(character[0])
    # The format to the char
    print(character[1])

# Get the third char (for instance)
my_char = characters[2]

# Get its format
my_char_format = my_char[1]

# Assign it a (existing) material index
my_char_format.material_index = 1
```

Comment: This is awesome. Didn't know you can assign materials to a text like this. Learned something new today :). Thnx.

Comment: @PaulGonet, Blender coders are awesome...

Comment: What did you use to grab your screen, with the keyboard labels in the corner and stuff?

Comment: @JasonC, it is an addon for the 3D View, called 'screencast keys'

Comment: That was great but after meshing the text, the color somehow reverts back to red

Comment: @TrulyTheCraziest, I don't have that here. How have you meshed the text? Alt+C ?

Comment: Nice Answer, I need to this but using python api how would you go about it? Thanks

Comment: @johnconnor, answer edited with a simple Python code to do it.

Comment: @lemon Thanks a lot.