# How to change text color with animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes, text-object

Is it possible to change color of some part of text object?

On image you can see a text object with 3 words inside (text different_color text).

two words should be black color and middle word (different_color) should be a white color.

pay attention, it`s all should be a text object (no convert to mesh).
 It should work automatically, so  if in text object   be more words , in that case the main word (different_color) always should be a white.
unfortunately this answer will not work for me [Can I colour the same text in two different colours?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74839/can-i-colour-the-same-text-in-two-different-colours)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use the *Character Properties Output* node as follows:

[image: Node Tree]